# Aop which in jar not working with springMvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-aop

FlowControlAsp.java:

```
@Aspect
@Order(8)
public class FlowControlAsp {
   @Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)")
   public void springMvcPointCut() {
   }

@Around("springMvcPointCut()")
public Object aroundMethod(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    //...
}
```

springMvc-servlet.xml:

```
<bean class="com.jar.FlowControlAsp"/>
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.walye.web" />
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

FlowControlAsp not working.

I copy com.jar.FlowControlAsp to my project and change config

```
<bean class="com.walye.FlowControlAsp"/>
```

FlowControlAsp works.

So how to make FlowControlAsp which in jar working with springMvc?

Comment: Can you show me your FlowControlAsp class? I want to know this class is using @Component annotation or not.

Comment: I just add @Aspect

Comment: The problem is in your component-scan tag. Change this tag like that <context:component-scan base-package="com" /> and try it again

Comment: still not working....

Comment: Why do you need an aspect? Generally when working with `@RequestMapping` you are better of using a `HandlerInterceptor` or properly integrate with Spring MVC.

Answer (score 0):

This apsect jar use aspectj-maven-plugin,and spring has a check for compiledByAjc.